# Is Ruby a good language for learning classical OO design patterns

Tags: javascript, ruby, design-patterns

My language of choice is Javascript. It is hard for me to grasp basic OO design patterns (GoF) with JS, since JS is very dynamic and it's inheritance model is  based on prototypes. At the same time I really like Coffeescript, which is influenced by Ruby syntax. I read somewhere that Ruby is a true Object-oriented language. Do you think that Ruby is a good choice for learning classical OO patterns ?

Thank you.

Comment: Ruby is good. Java is better, though (it has interfaces, strict types and other stuff)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ruby is nearly perfect to learn OOP, I strongly recommend it.
It is clear, simple, but powerful.

And, of course, big community is also pro for Ruby: you'll easily find tons of examples.

Comment: Did you mean heartily?